# ant -p equivalent in gruntjs?

Tags: ant, gruntjs, task

In `ant` I could provide descriptions of my targets which could then be shown using the `-p` option.

Is there a way to do this in gruntjs?  I haven't seen any inputs into either the `grunt.initConfig(...)` method or the `grunt.registerTask(..)` methods that allow you to enter a description to be displayed when running some kind of `ant -p` equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt --help` will list your tasks and their descriptions.

```
grunt.registerTask('taskname', 'task description', function() {});
grunt.registerTask('default', 'Run everything', ['taskname']);
```

There is an optional 2nd parameter for specifying a description.